# Why is the sklearn LDA transform VERY SLOW?

Tags: performance, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

I'm using sickit-learn Latent Dirichlet Allocation for topic modeling. The lda_object is fitted to a corpus of text. Now, we fit that to one text to understand the topic weights for it.

```
def append_lda_features(df, lda_vectorizer, tfidf+vector):

    from time import time
    st = time()

    lda_vector = lda_vectorizer.transform(tfidf_vector)

    print(time() - st)

    lda_vector = pd.DataFrame(lda_vector)
    lda_vector.columns = ['lda_word_'+str(i)
                           for i in range(lda_vectorizer.n_components)]
    return pd.concat([df, lda_vector], axis=1)
```

This is printing values around `0.67` seconds, which is really high. Considering that my lda only contains 15 components, and vectorizer has 100000 tokens:

`LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=15, n_jobs=30, verbose=1)`

What should I do to make the LDA work faster?

Answer (score 0):

When you're going to transform the `lda` on a single text vector, you better not set the `n_jobs = 1`.

In that way, it doesn't take that much time, as it doesn't need to parallelize the work, first. That apparently takes an obvious overhead.

```
def append_lda_features(df, lda_vectorizer, tfidf+vector):

    from time import time
    st = time()

    lda_vectorizer.n_jobs = 1
    lda_vector = lda_vectorizer.transform(tfidf_vector)

    print(time() - st)

    lda_vector = pd.DataFrame(lda_vector)
    lda_vector.columns = ['lda_word_'+str(i)
                           for i in range(lda_vectorizer.n_components)]
    return pd.concat([df, lda_vector], axis=1)
```

This one gives me about `0.01` seconds, instead on `0.6`